# JQuery datepicker yearrange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have 2 datepickers like this

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" data-year-range="2010:2016"/>
<input type="text" class="datepicker" data-year-range="2000:2020"/>
```

I have to define the `yearRange` for the 2 datepickers in configuration. So, I did like this.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    // $(this) isn't working here
    //yearRange : $(this).attr('data-year-range'),
    yearRange : $('.datepicker').attr('data-year-range')
});
```

But it is taking only `2010:2016` for the two datepickers. I don't understand why. The idea is to use different date ranges for the datepickers. Is it possible or do I need to define different datepickers?

Also, In datepickers is it possible to add the `yearRange` in html instead of the datepicker configuration?

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5fvc22f/1/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in following way:

https://jsfiddle.net/m5fvc22f/16/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.datepicker').each(function() {
       $(this).datepicker({
         changeYear: true,
         yearRange: $(this).data('year-range'),
       });
     })
   })
```

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki - no...this is working one. please try to run another solution and you will come to know what I am saying.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki - have you open the date picker and seen the range there in your fiddle? please do it.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki - this one actually works, the other one doesn't (at time of writing). Go ahead, try them both in JSFiddle

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki - I am waiting for your comments. The other person just updated the answer...;)!

Answer (score 1):

Try this : use `$(this)` instead of `$('.datepicker')`

```
$('.datepicker').each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange : $(this).data('year-range')
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m5fvc22f/25/)**